# Ajax response and anonymous function scope

Tags: ajax, jquery

In the following code

```
var entryTemplate = document.getElementById('entryTemplate');
entryTemplate = entryTemplate.firstChild;

for (var ipost in posts)
{
  var post = posts[ipost];
  var clone = entryTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  clone = $(clone);

  if (post.imageURL)
  {
    var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
    var largeImageURL = post.largeImageURL ? post.largeImageURL : post.imageURL;
    imgElement.src = post.thumbPresent ? POST_THUMB_URL + '/' + post.postID : largeImageURL;
    imgElement.alt = '';
    clone.find('div.BlogImageURL a').attr('href', largeImageURL).text(largeImageURL);
    clone.find('div.BlogImage a').attr('href', imgElement.src).append(imgElement);

    // get bytesize
    var postdata = 'inline_image_url=' + encodeURIComponent(post.imageURL);
    postdata += '&linked_image_url=' + encodeURIComponent(post.largeImageURL);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ASYNC_GET_BYTESIZE_URL,
    data: postdata,
    success: function(bytesize) {
      clone.find('.BlogImageBytesize').html(bytesize);
    }
    });
  }
  else
  {
    clone.find('div.BlogImageURL').text('(This post contains no images)');
    clone.find('div.BlogImage').remove();
  }

  $('#outputDiv').append(clone);
}

clone.find('.BlogImageBytesize').html(bytesize);
```

All ajax responses (bold line) modify the last *clone*, probably because the loop is finished when the first response arrives and *clone* points to the last *clone*.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could set `clone` as the `context` of your ajax call. (See [docs here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).) Then, I think it would work something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ASYNC_GET_BYTESIZE_URL,
    data: postdata,
    context: clone,
    success: function(bytesize) {
      $(this).find('.BlogImageBytesize').html(bytesize);
    }
});
```

I don't know for sure if the `context` has to be a plain DOM element or if it can be a jQuery object, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! In my case clone is already a jquery object, so I'm using this.find('.BlogImageBytesize').html(bytesize);